# ERROR dbeaver on manjaro

Tags: linux, arch-linux, database, sql-server, dbeaver

i downloaded dbeaver from the aur but it failed to open .

it gives :

" version 1.8 of JVM is not suitable for this product . Version 11 or greater is required"

but in the aur there is only one dbeaver release.

does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Remove Java 1.8?

Answer (score 1):

you need to check your java status

```
archlinux-java status

  java-17-openjdk (default)
  java-8-openjdk
```

if you don't see java-17
then first install

```
pacman -Syu jre-openjdk
```

and then set java-17 as default

```
archlinux-java set java-17-openjdk
```